# Print layout has extra space in right side of paper

Tags: visual-studio-2015, reportviewer

[image]

I set up report page to A4 size, but when I click print layout, it has extra space in right side of the paper.

Answer (score 0):

The issue happened because I scaled windows display setting to 125%. When I set the scale back to 100% it fixed the problem.